# How to separate the images in a folder based on the image number column of the Data frame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, cluster-analysis

I have the following Data Frame of shape (868, 3483) where 868 are the total number of images I have and 3481 are the number of pixels in an image. Each row represents a particular Image and the image number is in the `img` column. I have applied unsupervised learning and clustered these images which are in the `cluster` column.

```
img cluster 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0   3   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
1   2   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
2   3   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
3   1   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
5   3   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
6   3   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
8   3   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
9   3   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
10  2   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
11  2   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
13  3   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
15  1   1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0
```

I have a folder with the images labeled the same as the `img` column. Now I would like to segregate these images based on the cluster they belong to.

**For example** 
images '0,2,5,6,8,9,13' belong to cluster3 so I would like to segregate these images into a subfolder named 'cluster3' and same goes for cluster1 and cluster2.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: You can read the `img` number and its `cluster label`. Then move the image to the required folder using `shutil` library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move files based on the `os` (or `shutil` as Dennis commented, both work) module in python. From what I understand, we only care about the img and cluster columns

`dictionary = df.set_index("img")["cluster"].to_dict()` will return a dictionary with each key being an image and each cluster being a folder. 
I am not sure how many clusters exist, but we can create a number of folders and subfolders also with the os command, as shown below

```
#This is where you decide to save the images 
#Here you make individual folders for each cluster
fp = "path/to/save/images/clusters/"
import os
os.mkdir("clusters/")
allClusters = list(set(df["cluster"]))
for x in allClusters:
    os.mkdir(fp+"cluster" + str(x))
```

and then you can proceed to each file to its appropriate folder (I am not sure what the names of each file is, but for now I will assume the name is `img1.png, img2.png ...` etc.)
For your troubles I recommend renaming the img column (or some other column and setting the index to that column in the line below)

```
#This is where the dictionary is created. The key to each value is the 
#original file name
#The cluster value is the folder that each image will saved two (see above
#where we create each folder
dictionary = df.set_index("img")["cluster"].to_dict()
for x in dictionary:
    #THIS is how the file is acess, the dictionary stores the name of the
    #files as the key, and path to file is the folder of all those images
    filename = "path/to/images/" + str(x) + ".png" 

    #This is where we rename the original image to the new filepath
    os.rename(filename, fp + "cluster" + str(dictionary(x)) +"/"+ filename))
```

That should do the job. Let me know if there are any errors

Comment: @AkashTripuramallu I am unsure what you mean. In the code, I have written it so you can state a filepath? I recommend having a column of the dataframe being all the filenames (with path), using that column as the index for the dictionary (see above `df.set_index(image_names)[clusternames].to_dict()` and thus when you proceed to run os.rename, you rename file stored in the the key of the dictionary to a file in a folder named `cluster + str(cluster_num)`

Comment: Please mark this as correct if this answers your question

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: @AkashTripuramallu oops it is because windows machines use backslashes and not forward slashes. please change my code accordingly

Comment: I actually tried it but, it shows the same error. Any idea why?

Comment: @AkashTripuramallu sorry for the late reply. See the error I am seeing is that the folder name is `cluster2/` please change my code from part 1 above tho rename the folder from `cluster2/` to `cluster2\` and see if the error persist

Comment: I resolved the issue. That is because of the path error. Thank you for your time and support.